# Find all sub configurations for a configuration

Tags: gradle

When adding a dependency using `beforeResolve`, it is added only to the specified configuration but none of the configurations that have the configuration as a super configuration.

Ie, when using the `java` plugin, you have the default configurations `compile`, `runtime`, `testCompile`, and `testRuntime`.  The configurations inherit as follows:

- `compile` <- `runtime`
- `testCompile` <- `testRuntime`
- `runtime` <- `testRuntime`

If I add dependency `'com.example:foo:1.0'` to the `compile` configuration using a normal dependency block, it will get inherited into the `runtime`, `testCompile`, and `testRuntime` configurations.  If I add that same dependency using a `beforeResolve` block, it never gets inherited into any configurations.

Is there a way for me to determine which configurations extend a given configuration?  All I can seem to find is the [`Configuration#extendsFrom(Configuration)`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#extendsFrom(org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration...)) method which allows the addition of a superconfiguation to a configuration.

---

### Solution

It seems that I was looking for the sub configurations, not the super configurations.  Since that data isn't readily available, I adapted the accepted answer to my needs.  Basically, for each configuration in the project, get all of its super configurations.  If the configuration we want is one of the super configurations for a configuration, that configuration is a sub configuration.

```
/**
 * Get all Configurations that extend the provided configuration, including
 * the one that is specified.
 * 
 * @param config the configuration to get all sub configurations for
 * @param p the project to get the configurations from
 * 
 * @return set of all unique sub configurations of the provided configuration
 */
private static Set<String> getSubConfigs(final Configuration config, final Project p)
{
    final Set<String> subConfs = new HashSet<>()
    subConfs.add(config.name)
    p.configurations.each {
        if (getSuperConfigs(it, p).contains(config.name))
        {
        subConfs.add(it.name)
        }
    }
    return subConfs
}

/**
 * Get all super configurations for a given Configuration.
 * 
 * @param config the configuration to get all super configurations for
 * @param p the project to get the configurations from
 * 
 * @return set of all unique super configurations of the provided configuration
 */
private static Set<String> getSuperConfigs(final Configuration config, final Project p) 
{
    final Set<String> superConfs = new HashSet<>()
    superConfs.add(config.name)
    config.extendsFrom.each {
        superConfs.addAll(getSuperConfigs(p.configurations[it.name], p))
    }
    return superConfs
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [Configuration#getExtendsFrom](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#getExtendsFrom()) returns the set of superconfigurations for the given configuration. You can print the list of superconfigurations of a given configuration as

```
task printConfig {
    configurations.testRuntime.extendsFrom.each { println it.name }
}
```

This however does not list the superconfigurations of the superconfiguration (i.e., recursive list). But a little code around this would give the complete list

```
ext.configList = new HashMap<String, String>()
def getSuperConfigs(config) {
    config.extendsFrom.each {
        configList.put(it.name, '1')
        getSuperConfigs(configurations[it.name])
    }
}
task printConfig {
    getSuperConfigs(configurations['testRuntime'])
    configList.each {
        println it.key
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for the other direction (I guess I got my super/sub terminology backwards).  Using this code sample, I was able to build what I needed.